# Npm script fails - '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, npm

This is the error log

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cloudenly-hr-microservice@1.0.0 prestart: `sequelize db:migrate  && ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:seed:all`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cloudenly-hr-microservice@1.0.0 prestart script.
```

Here is the script

```
    "lint": "eslint",
    "test": "export NODE_ENV=test && mocha --timeout 100000",
    "prestart": "./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate  && ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:seed:all",
    "start": "./node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 start pm2server.config.js",
    "poststart": "./node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 log HumanR"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on Windows, but trying to run a script designed for linux (it has linux path separators, which confuse Windows).

Inside an npm script, you can refer to locally installed package binaries by name. Doing so will eliminate your path issue.

```
    "test": "export NODE_ENV=test && mocha --timeout 100000",
    "prestart": "sequelize db:migrate  && sequelize db:seed:all",
    "start": "pm2 start pm2server.config.js",
    "poststart": "pm2 log HumanR"
```

You might also run into an issue with the `export NODE_ENV=test` command. You'll need [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) for that.

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

Then in package.json:

```
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha --timeout 100000",
```

Comment: i replaced the script with what you gave above, it works well but database does not connect

Comment: @Yhomi were you able to get the database to connect?

Comment: yes, i had to change the script to the above

Answer (score -1):

Does `.bin` folder in `"./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate  && ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:seed:all"` exists?

I have something similar in a project, but I do this:

```
    "db:seed": "npm run _db -- db:seed:all",
    "db:create": "npm run _db -- db:create",
    "db:migrate": "npm run _db -- db:migrate",
    "db:init": "./scripts/create_and_seed_db.sh",
    "_db": "node ./node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/sequelize",
```